# AWS allow trafic from another Elastic beanstalk or EC2 with changing IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

I have 2 accounts where one is a Elastic Beanstalk (Account A). I want another account(B) EC2 should allow traffic only from account A's Elastic Beanstalk.
How to handle this if the IP of Elastic Beanstalk from account A changes.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit off. Elastic Beanstalk instances don't have Elastic IPs, they just have public IPs. If they had Elastic IPs then the addresses would never change, and you wouldn't be posting about this issue.

Comment: @MarkB yeah, I just corrected the question. So the IP changes if I change instance in Elastic beanstalk and I end up in updating the same in another security group to allow traffic. any solution for this?

Comment: There's no solution to this using the public IPs. You could setup cross-account VPC peering and then use public IPs and whitelist the security groups.